# Why can't I link to Rick Astley in iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube, url-scheme

No, wait, don't go!  I'm serious.

I was (am?) attempting to rickroll my coworkers in celebration of defeating the iOS beast in our latest battle, when the hydra decided to get the last laugh.  Clicking on links to, or `openURL` with, either of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0 (the two major rickrolling videos) results in a "Could not load movie" error.  But when I find the video through the Youtube app, it plays fine.  Other video URLs chosen at random and run through the exact same pathways work fine.

I'm not sure how else to ask this, other than WTF?  Could Apple / Youtube be special-casing these videos?

Answer (score 2):

Official music videos often have all kinds of restrictions for mobile playback... try a less popular video of the song?

Comment: The OP's links are for Flash Devices only, no matter if a video is not popular, it will not play with that markup. See my answer for correct markup.

Comment: Your links don't work on iPad either. It's restricted content.

Comment: Replacing those Video ID's with different one's that are allowed. Also, if you remove autoplay option, you can see the Poster. I have update the example with a different VideoID that works.

Comment: That's generally what I've assumed, but if you search for the videos in the Youtube app, they're 100% playable.  Unless this is standard behavior for restricted content (fails on link, succeeds on search) (a definite possibility, but weird), something else seems to be going on here.

Comment: I think the app is related to marketing tie-ins and other ways to monitor what's played. Also, it's more about licensing rights of rebroadcasting from the copy-write holders.

Answer (score 1):

**STATUS:** Although the OP's VideoID's are restricted for viewing on YouTube website only, this is the method to watch YouTube Videos on iOS Devices.

You will need to link using YouTube's **Embed URL Method** for iOS.

Example links:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID
http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?autoplay=1
```

**NOTE:** The second links is formatted with **YouTube autoplay Option**.

---

**Status Update:** See this [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11270639/1195891) that may prove useful. As those answer comments state, iOS will swap out the HTML tags automatically.

Comment: Those open up Safari with a full-screen preview, which is pretty far from the documented URLs that open and auto-play a video: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007895-SW1 .  Those links do however tell me "This video contains content from Vevo.  It is restricted from playback on certain sites.".  Maybe that has something to do with it?  But it works in the Youtube app...

Comment: You can add on the YouTube query string to invoke Autoplay, but because has decided to allow viewing only on their website, these videos links will not work, only the syntax method for which I have provided.

Comment: @Groxx I have a working example for you using a different VideoId. Please see updated link.

Comment: Those don't work for me (iPod).  They show the preview (again in Safari, not the Youtube app), but the autoplay doesn't autoplay. Changing them to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9387zmssuE works perfectly - launches the app, auto-plays, everything.  Same as many other videos.  But not the main Rick Astley ones.

Comment: Ah, well... keep the method shown above in mind. Many videos at YouTube are not reconverted to HTML5 Video yet. Hum, maybe you can try to OPT-IN their HTML5 Video Trial. Visit [here](http://www.youtube.com/html5) to enable and disable HTML5 YouTube Video.

Comment: If they weren't converted, I would think they wouldn't play at all in the app.

Comment: Not all videos are in all file-formats, there's a lot to be done which is why YouTube has not fully launched their HTML5 outside of the trial... but it's developing well.

Answer (score 1):

> Could Apple / Youtube be special-casing these videos?

Sure, they might. The [Wikipedia entry on "rickrolling"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling) says this:

> The meme is a bait and switch; a person provides a hyperlink seemingly
>   relevant to the topic at hand, but actually leads to Astley's video.

Fooling the user is very much against the spirit of the iOS app store review guidelines, and it's probable that you're not the first person to try this. So it's possible that certain videos are special-cased, or that certain videos are marked with an attribute that prevents them from loading.

Further down in the article, [Wikipedia also says:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling#iPhone_worm)

> In October/November 2009, a worm designed to infect jailbroken iPhones
>   changed the wallpaper of infected phones to a picture of Rick Astley
>   overlaid with the text "ikee is never going to give you up".

This seems like an even better reason for iOS to have code that avoids videos involving Rick Astley. Not that the worm is directly connected to the videos, but if the unexpected appearance of Rick Astley is a meme that's associated with malware, you can imagine Apple wanting to prevent loading such content by untrusted apps.

Comment: Every time I read questions like this, I'm reminded why I (as a user) really appreciate Apple's policies. Sure, they're sometimes frustrating to those app developers among us who would never do anything to violate the user's trust and yet feel constrained by the seemingly-arbitrary limitations. But you have to remember that not everyone is as scrupulous as you and I, and that a positive experience for the user is the ultimate goal of everyone involved.