# youtube embed video not working with safari

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have a simple page with this HTML code :

```
<iframe width="100%" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5FSsednibXQ?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

It is working fine in chrome but not in safari. I only have the black box with safari.
Any idea ? What is the correct way to embed a youtube video in safari ?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: Try this:
Safari > Preferences > Privacy
 
Block cookies:
 
Set it to "Never" and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<object>
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</object>
```

It's explained here:
[Making youtube.com/embed URLs work on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969334/making-youtube-com-embed-urls-work-on-ios)