# Youtube video given in iframe tag but its not working in Safari browser

Tags: html, video, iframe, youtube

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/alswD2tCc_Q?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Hi All,

Above is my code.  The video is working in all browsers besides Safari.Can you guys help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this answer, it might solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34760448/6654987

Answer (score 0):

Safari requires webserver to support "[Range][1]" request header in order to play your media content.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone/CreatingVideoforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006514-SW6

For a legit "Range" request response, your webserve need to return status code "206".