# Youtube embedded video not clickable. How do I fix it?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

For school we need to make a website with a screencast. I have uploaded the video to YouTube and put it embedded in the website. The video shows up but it isn't clickable. When I try autoplay it plays on my friends computer (windows, chrome) but he can't click. On my computer (Mac, Safari) it doesn't even play, it is still on the first frame. Does anyone know how to fix this???

Here's the code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/qo6rGlgzKWI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There is no css yet.

It is inside a div with just normal text.

Comment: please don't add the `embedded` tag, it is for microcomputer systems and not for embedding an html page inside another

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this one works fine on mac safari

```html
 <iframe id="myythtml5player" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" width="560" height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/qo6rGlgzKWI" data-tooltip-align="b,c" data-tooltip="YouTube video player" aria-label="YouTube video player" data-title="YouTube video player"></iframe>
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/jxfoywb2/

see this answer : [youtube embed video not working with safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494102/youtube-embed-video-not-working-with-safari)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I think I will just put a link. :(

Comment: @EiseZimmerman did you allow auto play on safari settings ? as its blocked by default and you need to allow it manualy See here : https://support.apple.com/en-mn/guide/safari/ibrw29c6ecf8/mac