# Joomla website, iframe videos can not be displayed on Safari

Tags: iframe, safari, joomla

When I use an iframe on my page to show a Vimeo video, it works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in Safari Desktop. 
Here is the error:

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot
>   be made.

I have checked all similar questions and can't see any solutions that work. 
Specially [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969334/making-youtube-com-embed-urls-work-on-ios):

```
<object>
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/[VIDEO_ID]" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</object>
```

The above code is the most upvoted answer, however it shows the following error on the page:

> Missing Plug-in

Answer (score 0):

The Missing Plugin error, is due to modern browsers no longer supporting Flash. A more modern solution is Media Element

http://www.mediaelementjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there how this works with a Joomla website? It does not have any plugin for Joomla